# Bash, показать содержимое третьего столбец текстового файла, при условии, что в первых двух столбцах есть пустые ячейки

Tags: linux, bash, консоль

Пример файла my_file.txt:

```
A B C
  D E
F   G
```

Я хочу получить:

```
C
E
G
```

Что пробовал:

```
cut -d' ' -f3 my_file1.txt
awk '{print $3}' my_file.txt
```

В файле в пустых местах пробел, он же и использутеся, как разделитель, в результате чего ответ получается не тот что я хочу. Пробую через регулярные выражения, но пока без успешно.

Помогите найти решение.

Comment: А в значениях пробелов не бывает?
А столбцы одинаковой ширины?

Comment: В значениях пробелы, столбцы одинаковые

Comment: Так может тогда проще вывести все символы с 5 столбца?

Comment: Для упрощения переделал в латинские буквы по факту в третьем столбы string разной длины. 
Сорян,  в первый раз не понял про ширину столбцов.

Comment: Если столбцов максимум 3, то надо печатать последний (например, awk-ом)

Comment: Покажите более близкий к жизни пример

Answer (score 3):

Если всего 3 столбца, то

```
awk '{print $NF}'
```

выводит последний столбец, в данном случае 3. На твоем примере работает.

Answer (score 0):

Может что-то такое?

```
$ cat table.txt 
First Second Third
1     2      3
      22     33
111          333
             Only-Third
No    Third
E     N      D

$ cat table.txt | cut -c 14-
Third
3
33
333
Only-Third

D
```

Answer (score 0):

> В файле в пустых местах пробел, он же и использутеся, как разделитель
>
> В значениях пробелы, столбцы одинаковые
>
> в третьем столбы string разной длины

допустим у нас есть таблица из трёх столбцов где разделителем значений выступает один пробел, кроме последнего столбца, где в значении также могут встречаться пробелы. Если значение пусто то оно заменяется на один пробел.
пример таблицы

```
A B C 1
  D E 2 2
F    
  G  
H   I 3 3 3
    J 4 4 4 4
```

нужно вывести последний(третий) столбец

```
S='_'; cat FILE |awk '{print " "$0}' |sed "s/  / $S/g" |cut -d' ' -f 4- |tr "$S" ' '
```

где переменная `S` это временный односимвольный *"заменитель"* для пустого поля, этот символ не должен встречаться в таблице, `_` можно заменить на другой символ.

на выходе получим:

```
C 1
E 2 2
 
 
I 3 3 3
J 4 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Для вашего примера работает такой алгоритм:

```
$ cat f
A B C
  D E
F   G

$ sed 's/   / , /g;s/  /, /g' f | awk '{if($1 ~ "," || $2 ~ ",")print $3}'
E
G
```

Сначала sed'ом переделываем 3-е и 2-е пробелы в соотв. комбинации с например "," затем awk'ом проверяем если 1-й или 2-й столбец содержат "," выводим 3-й столбец.